# how to subtract items in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have two lists of items for each customer, ItemListA and ItemListB

```
Customer_id   ItemListA   ItemListB
   24            2,3         3,4,5
   26            6,7         8,9,10
   25            4,5          5,8
```

And I want Items in ItemListB that are not in ItemListA so the output should be:

```
Customer_id   ItemListB_A
     24          4,5
     26          8,9,10
     25          4,8
```

I don't know how I can subtract items from two strings in Hive. I know of COLLECT_SET but it can remove duplicated but not remove the item intersection.

Comment: Comma-delimited lists is not the SQLish way to store things.  You should have a separate table with one row per customer and per item.

Comment: Ok so that is how it was right now. How do I convert it into one row per customer kind of table?

Comment: If your longest list is short, you could manually run an insert into another table of the last ',value' then update every row with ',value' to remove that part of the string. Repeat until there are no more commas.

Comment: The example for `Customer_id` `25` is wrong. `ItemListB_A` Should be `8`

Answer (score 0):

This will give the desired result.

```
  select Customer_id, collect_list(y) from
    (select Customer_id, y , count(*) as cnt from 
    (select Customer_id,y from (select Customer_id, split(concat_ws(',',ItemListA,ItemListB),',') as x from table_name) temp lateral view explode(x) temp as y) temp1 
    group by Customer_id,y  ) temp2 where cnt =1 group by Customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select      customer_id

           ,split
            (
                regexp_replace
                (
                    concat(ItemListB,',:,',ItemListA)
                   ,'(?<=^|,)(?<item>.*?),(?=.*(?<=,)\\k<item>(?=,|$))'
                   ,''
                )
               ,',?:'
            )[0]        as ItemListB_A

from        mytable
```

---

```
+-------------+-------------+
| customer_id | itemlistb_a |
+-------------+-------------+
|          24 | 4,5         |
|          26 | 8,9,10      |
|          25 | 8           |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select      customer_id
           ,concat_ws (',',collect_list (item)) as ItemListB_A

from       (select      t.customer_id
                       ,pe.item

            from        mytable     t
                        lateral view posexplode (split (concat_ws(',',ItemListA,ItemListB),',')) pe as pos,item

            group by    t.customer_id
                       ,pe.item

            having      count (case when pos < size(split(ItemListA,',')) then 1 end) = 0  
            ) t

group by    customer_id
```

---

```
+-------------+-------------+
| customer_id | itemlistb_a |
+-------------+-------------+
|          24 | 4,5         |
|          25 | 8           |
|          26 | 10,8,9      |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.Customer_id,concat_ws (',',collect_list (a.item)) as ItemListB_A from (            
select      t.Customer_id
                       ,pe.item

            from        test_hive     t
                        lateral view posexplode (split (concat_ws(',',ItemListB),',')) pe as pos,item
                        lateral view posexplode (split (concat_ws(',',ItemListA),',')) pe1 as pos1,item1
            group by t.Customer_id,pe.item
            having count(case when item=item1 then 1 end)=0
)a
group by a.Customer_id
```